# NameError: name 'self' is not defined when trying to make a module

Tags: python

I have two files

**check.py**

```
import UrlParsing as owm

API_key = 'private_API_Key'

obj1 = owm.OWM(API_key)
cd = obj1.three_hours_forecast("London, uk")
print(cd)
```

and **UrlParsing.py**

```
import urllib

class OWM(object):
    def __init__(self, API_key):
        self.API_key = API_key

    def three_hours_forecast(city, country):
        cty = city
        api_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={},{}&mode=json&units=metric&APPID={}".format(cty, country, self.API_key)
        data_dictionary = get_dict(api_url)
        return data_dictionary

    def get_dict(self, api_url):
        url = urllib.urlopen(api_url)
        output_data = url.read().decode('utf-8')
        data_dict = json.loads(output_data)
        url.close()
        print(data_dict)
        return data_dict
```

I am trying to create a UrlParsing module so that I can use it in my main program. Can some one please tell me what is wrong with the program. I am getting NameError: name 'self' is not defined.

What did I do wrong? and can you please tell me how to correct it. I tried to do some follow up on the same questions but I had no luck. I appreciate any help.

Error traces beck to this line

```
        api_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={},{}&mode=json&units=metric&APPID={}".format(cty, country, self.API_key)
```

Comment: You aren't passing in `self` as the first parameter for  `three_hours_forecast`

Comment: You forgot the `self` argument in `three_hours_forecast`, and you forgot to put `self.` on the `get_dict` call inside that function.

Comment: When I try to do that it is saying few arguments are called an throwing an error

Comment: did you try `def three_hours_forecast(self, city, country)` ?

Comment: TypeError: three_hours_forecast() missing 1 required positional argument: 'country'
I am getting this error

Comment: Are you trying to call it as a static method?

Comment: in this line: `cd = obj1.three_hours_forecast("London, uk")` you're passing city and country in the same parameter.. try: `cd = obj1.three_hours_forecast("London", "uk")`

Answer (score 4):

You could try

**check.py**

```
cd = obj1.three_hours_forecast("London", "uk")
```

**UrlParsing.py**

```
def three_hours_forecast(self, city, country):
        cty = city
        api_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={},{}&mode=json&units=metric&APPID={}".format(cty, country, self.API_key)
        data_dictionary = get_dict(api_url)
        return data_dictionary
```

I hope this help you.